# C# Console How to Start the Program with XML Deserialize from Previous Data

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

My console program consists of a generic List with 4 values already in it when the console starts. The user can only input one more name into the list. I want my program to be able to serialize the data before closing. And I am able to deserialize from the xml file to print out all five names when the program start. The serialize part works properly. And I can also deserialize if I put my deserialize code right below the serialize part. But that defeats the purpose of being able to load your data from previous usage. Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace serializationtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> ListOfName = new List<string>();
            ListOfName.Add("Bob");
            ListOfName.Add("Mary");
            ListOfName.Add("Peter");
            ListOfName.Add("May");
            ListOfName.Add(null);


            Console.WriteLine("Fill in the last name");
            ListOfName[4] = Console.ReadLine();
            XmlSerializer ListOfNameSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
            TextWriter FileSaveListOfName = new StreamWriter(@"ListofName.xml");
            ListOfNameSerializer.Serialize(FileSaveListOfName, ListOfName);
            FileSaveListOfName.Close();
            XmlSerializer ListOfNameDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
            FileStream ReadTheList = new FileStream(@"ListofName.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            ListOfName = (List<string>)ListOfNameSerializer.Deserialize(ReadTheList);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for the existance of the file you serialize to; if its there, deserialize, otherwise create everything from scratch like you did. Then continue program flow.

Comment: The file is there after I serialize, and I can deserialize it at the end of my program. However, I want to be able to deserialize the existing file at the start of my program the second time I run it. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Well if you havent already run the program, no file, so my approach should work fine. I just dont have the time to outline in detail to you. Sorry. Ill get to it tomorrow in the morning.

Comment: After going back and forth, I think the problem is my path to the file itself. If I use the default path (@"NameOfFile"), I can deserialize the file to another xmlserializer object with no issue. When I put the file in my C:\users\, the program gave me XML document (0, 0) error when I tried to deserialize the file at the start of my program. Is there anyway for me to avoid that problem? I should be able to put my file in any path correct?

Comment: Open the two files with notepad and compare the files.  I suspect you are not writing the end of the file properly.  Try adding a Flush() method just before your existing Close() method.

Comment: It is weird. The program works properly now even when I put the file in my C:\ . It could have been a typo in my code somewhere when I tried it the last time. Thank for all the help.